# Timer for individual <div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, webrtc

I'm currently trying to set a timer for each div created, whereby each div has a background color of green or red depending on if there are detections in the webRTC video. Is there a way to assign a timer to the divs individually? Or maybe to only check for my own video? I've tried something like below, but it does not work when there are more than 1 people in the call, as "time" will be a global variable. I've also tried something like  `time = Math.ceil((time+1)/checkerBox.length)` , but it does not seem to work too. Any pointers will be helpful

```
function checker(){
    var time =0;
     var timer = setInterval(function (){

        for(var i=0;i<checkerBox.length;i++){

                if(checkerBox[i].style.backgroundColor=="red"){
                   time = time + 1;
                    console.log("Box" + videoNum[i].innerHTML + " is not present for : " + checkerBox[i].innerHTML  + " seconds");
                }else{
                    time = 0;
                }
                
                //Exceed time
                if(checkerBox[i].innerHTML == 30){
                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                        takeScreenshot(videoNum[i-1]);
                    }, 100);
                    
                    time = 0;
                }

                checkerBox[i].innerHTML =  time;
        }

       },1000)
}
```

Update : I ended up using arrays

```
 var takenFrom;
    var d = new Date();
    let timeKeep = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    let screenShots = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

    function checker(){
        timer = setInterval(function (){
            for(var i=0;i<=(checkerBox.length)-1;i++){

                tableRow[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML = timeKeep[i]
                tableRow[i+1].cells[3].innerHTML = screenShots[i]  

                if(flag[i].innerHTML=="0"){
                    checkerBoxFalse(checkerBox[i]);
                    timeKeep[i] = timeKeep[i] + 1;
                    console.log("Box" + videoNum[i].innerHTML + " is not present for : " +  tableRow[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML  + " seconds");
                        if(tableRow[i+1].cells[2].innerHTML == 10 ){
                            takenFrom = "Box" + videoNum[i].innerHTML + "minute" + d.getMinutes() + " room" + ROOM_ID 
                            takeScreenshot(videoNum[i],takenFrom);
                            screenShots[i] = screenShots[i] + 1;
                            timeKeep[i] = 0;
                        }
                } else if(flag[i].innerHTML== "1"){
                    checkerBoxTrue(checkerBox[i]);
                    timeKeep[i] = 0;
                } 
            }
        },1000)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
for (let div of divs) {
    setInterval(function() {
        //do something with div
    }, 1000);
}
```

`let` is block scoped, so each `setInterval` will have its own `div`.

Comment: I ended up using arrays ``` let timeKeep = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);``` and incrementing the values within, corresponding to the index of the video call box